# How do I fill in Formfields in Word-Documents?

Tags: python, ms-word

Sorry in advance... I´m a python- AND stackoverflow-newbie.

But I have a problem and I hope there is a solution for my problem... I try to use python for filling in the default text in word-document form fields but unfortunately I haven't been successful yet:
[image: How to access this default text?]

My colleague played around with `win32com` and found a way to overwrite the form field, but not to insert something. Is there anybody who had a similar problem? In the end the goal is to fill in the form fields of word-templates automatically.

Edit:
Our current approach with `win32com`:

```py
Dict = {
    "Value1": "123456789",
    "Value2": "test",
    "Value3": "42"
}
def wordExport(Dict, docPath):

    wordApp = win32com.client.Dispatch('Word.Application') 

    wordApp.Visible = False
    doc = wordApp.Documents.Open(docPath) 
    marks = doc.FormFields 
    cMarks = marks.Count

    for i in range(1, cMarks + 1):
        fieldName = str(marks(i).Name) 

        if fieldName in Dict:
            keyValue = Dict.get(fieldName)
            resultIsEmpty = not marks(i).Result 
        
            if keyValue != "None":
                marks(i).Result = keyValue + " "   

    doc.Close()
    wordApp.Visible = False
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @Jammmme its helpful to include code snippets of what you have tried it will give  you a better chance at receiving a response. Also it helps those answering the questions know where you are coming from and their answers can be better tailored directly to you.

Comment: I am not sure as I never do it and can't test but I think you should play with [statustext](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office/vba/api/word.formfield.statustext) , [checkbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office/vba/api/word.formfield.checkbox) and [drop-down](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office/vba/api/word.formfield.dropdown)

Comment: Why are you doing that instead of using a Word template with the defaults already set?

Comment: @DanielButler thank you for your comment. I added the python code we are using so far. Hope I did it correct! :D

Comment: @macropod Could you elaborate your idea a bit? Unfortunately I don´t get what you mean exactly...

Comment: @DonKnacki Thanks for your suggestion... I´ll have a look on it!

Comment: *Every* document in Word is based on a template. The default is named 'Normal.dotm'. You can create a document containing all your 'boilerplate' content, including formfields with their defaults, then save it as a Word Template (e.g. MyForm.dotx or MyForm.dotm, depending on whether it contains macros). Your current macro could then create a new document from that template via Set doc = wordApp.Documents.Add(filepath/MyForm.dotx), and not need code to generate any of that content.